# Building OpenBLAS with OpenMP: Cannot set number of OpenMP threads

Tags: python, multithreading, numpy, openmp, openblas

I'm trying to run Numpy with OpenBLAS and OpenMP, but I can't seem to get `OMP_NUM_THREADS` to alter the number of threads used.

I compiled OpenBLAS from source using `USE_OPENMP=1`, and to confirm I got the correct build,

```
OpenBLAS build complete. (BLAS CBLAS)

OS               ... Linux             
Architecture     ... x86_64               
BINARY           ... 64bit                 
C compiler       ... GCC  (command line : gcc)
Library Name     ... libopenblas_haswellp-r0.3.0.dev.a (Multi threaded; Max num-threads is 48)

Use OpenMP in the multithreading. Because of ignoring OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS and GOTO_NUM_THREADS flags, 
you should use OMP_NUM_THREADS environment variable to control the number of threads.
```

I exported `OMP_DYNAMIC=false`, exported `USE_OPENMP=1` and set `OMP_NUM_THREADS` to different values, but no luck. And when I check the library linking for Numpy with OpenBLAS:

```
$ ldd openblas/numpy/core/multiarray.so 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffcedba9000)
    libopenblas.so.0 => /opt/openblas-OpenMP/lib/libopenblas.so.0 (0x00007f78ab9ae000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f78ab6ac000)
    libpython2.7.so.1.0 => /lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0 (0x00007f78ab2e1000)
    libgomp.so.1 => /lib64/libgomp.so.1 (0x00007f78ab0bb000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f78aae9f000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f78aaade000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f78ac350000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f78aa8da000)
    libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f78aa6d7000)
```

So I see that **libgomp.so.1** is being linked, which means that I've got Numpy built with OpenMP. As I said, I set the dynamic threading to `false`, so where am I going wrong? I'm trying to call `numpy.cholesky`

Edit: I'm running on RHEL 7.3

Comment: From your python script try... `numpy.show_config()` and verify that `blas_opt_info` is setup with openblas.  I've had issues in the past where I've had 2 version of numpy (one in /usr/lib and one in /usr/local/lib) and I was inadvertently loading the one that was setup for the old blas.